# How can I add tabs to this Tk application in Python 3.12.0?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an app where there is a `main` function that looks like this:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("MyApp")

#Set the initial size of the window and make it resizeable
root.geometry("1024x768")
root.resizable(True,True)

app = AudioPlayer(master=root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
app.mainloop()
```

and a class that looks like this:

```
class AudioPlayer(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets() #Spawn the GUI
```

Finally, my `create_widgets()` method looks like this:

```
def create_widgets(self):
    """
    Creates the individual items in the Tk window, and specifies which handlers to call when they are interacted with
    """
    # Frame for Sample buttons
    sample_button_frame = Frame(self)
    sample_button_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=5, pady=5)
    # Sample Filter Buttons
    self.button_kick = Button(sample_button_frame, text="Kick", command=self.filter_kick)
    self.button_kick.pack(side="left",padx=5)
    self.button_clap = Button(sample_button_frame,text="Clap",command=self.filter_clap)
    self.button_clap.pack(side="left",padx=5)
```

The app currently works fine. The problem is that I need to now after-the-fact, add tabs to this app. I want everything that already exists to be in Tab 1, and I want to add another tab for the new features I am about to introduce. I understand I need to use a `Notebook`. What I do not understand is how I need to set this class and the instantiation up so that all of the current widgets are attached to Tab 1 rather than the main Tk `root` Frame. I have attempted to alter `main` to do the following:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("MyApp")

#Set the initial size of the window and make it resizeable
root.geometry("1024x768")
root.resizable(True,True)
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = Frame(notebook)
tab2 = Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(tab1,text="Tab 1")
notebook.add(tab2, text="Tab 2")
app = AudioPlayer(root, notebook)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
app.mainloop()
```

However, this is not working as intended. The `AudioPlayer` class doesn't seem to properly communicate to the widgets that I need to add the widgets to `Tab 1` under this configuration. As a final example, I attemped to do this:

`sample_button_frame = Frame(tab1)`

And now when I run the app GUI, the entire `sample_button_frame` is missing and there are no tabs at the top.

Comment: There is no `tab1` and `tab2`, do you mean `tab_finder` and `tab_sample_dirs` instead? Also simply create `AudioPlayer` as child of `tab_finder` and it will be created inside "Tab 1".

Comment: @acw1668 I fixed this, I renamed the symbols to make the explanation simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create `tab1` as an instance of `AudioPlayer`:

```py
root = Tk()
root.title("MyApp")
root.geometry("1024x768")
root.resizable(True,True)
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = AudioPlayer(notebook) # tab1 as an instance of AudioPlayer
tab2 = Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(tab1, text="Tab 1")
notebook.add(tab2, text="Tab 2")
notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=1) # show the notebook
root.mainloop()
```

Note that you don't need to call `self.pack()` inside `AudioPlayer.__init__()`.

Comment: I had no idea that I could just pass `notebook` into AudioPlayer like this and that I could then run `root.mainloop()` and pack the notebook instead. This is a great, concise, and accurate answer.

Comment: quick follow-up, how can I access the second tab in this configuration? Is it accessible from within the AudioPlayer instance? I see it visually in the GUI now, but Im not sure if the tabs are accessible from within there or if I need to set `tab2 = SomeOtherClass(notebook)` if that makes sense.

Comment: @the_endian It is better to raise another question.

Comment: I figured it out - if anyone is curious how to accesss tab2, you can indeed make a separate class and set `tab2 = SomeNewClass(notebook)`, granted that class inherits from e.g. `tk.Frame` and calls `super().__init__()` and that will allow you to then create widgets in there on `self`.

Comment: Line number 5: line 6: tab1 = AudioPlayer(notebook) . It is not required to be this way. It can be just : tab1 = ttk.Frame(notebook) and tab2 = ttk.Frame(notebook.). The idea is: be default notebook 's tab-1 becomes the 1st instance